# How does the Space Shuttle's SSME engine's thrust vary after ignition?

Tags: space-shuttle, engine-design, ssme

After writing the question [Do Blue Origin's BE-3 engines need to run for 7 seconds to “warm up”?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/26994/12102), I took a look at the YouTube video [SSME ignition sequence](https://youtu.be/NjZ9ly7c08s) (found in [What are the small gas jets at the rims of the Space Shuttle Main Engines?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/15464/12102)) showing the Space Shuttle's main SSME engines, and they also take several seconds from the first appearance of burning exhaust to *what looks like* a stable, full thrust before the clamps are released and the shuttle begins to rise.

**note:** the connection is that both engines use LOX/LH2

What is happening here? How do the propellant flow rates and more importantly the resulting thrust vary versus time during this ignition sequence?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a lot of good, detailed information about SSME startup and shutdown in "[Space Shuttle Main Engine - the first 10 years Part 3](http://large.stanford.edu/courses/2011/ph240/nguyen1/docs/SSME_PRESENTATION.pdf)".

The answers to this highly related question [What are the phases of ignition (and flameout) of a liquid fuel engine?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/13095/what-are-the-phases-of-ignition-and-flameout-of-a-liquid-fuel-engine) discuss many of the start parameters for the SSME but not the thrust.

This includes graphs of start parameters including chamber pressure (MCC PC).

[image]

Thrust is roughly proportional to PC. A thrust curve isn't shown in this paper, but here's a simplified one from my notes from working on the engine model in the Shuttle Mission Simulator.  Units are lbf on the vertical axis, seconds on the horizontal.

[image]

Edit: Just noticed you asked about flowrates too.  Again from SMS SSME model notes, here are simplified plots of the startup flowrates.  Red is LO2, blue is LH2, Y axis units are lbm/sec.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Also see the following thrust curves, from:
https://gandalf.azureedge.net/shuttle.html (If anybody knows the Docents for Enterprise in New York or for Endeavour in Los Angeles please pass these links to them)
Specifically:
https://gandalfddi.z19.web.core.windows.net/Shuttle/Shuttle_And_Misc_Pictures/ascent.gif

[image]